# how to connect sql server using window auth using clojure?

Tags: sql-server, clojure

I know how to connect using sql auth. But how to use windows auth?

```
(use 'clojure.java.jdbc)
(require '[clojure.java.jdbc :as j])
(def db {:classname "com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver"
               :subprotocol "sqlserver"
               :subname "//localhost;database=test;user=sa;password=sa"

})
```

Comment: can I assume you mean Microsoft SQL server, active directory and kerberos/NTLM login?

Comment: Also struggling with it. I wonder how to add sqljdbc_auth.dll to classpath cause I get such error ```:cause no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What abount `:subname "//localhost;database=test;integratedSecurity=true;` ?

reference : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspxhttp://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspx#Connectingintegrated